# Visual Studio Code - Prevent Intellisense popup without disabling Intellisense completely

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

When Intellisense is enabled in Visual Studio Code, VS Code will continually produce pop-up windows as you type with autocomplete suggestions.

The user can then select one of these by pressing tab, enter, etc.

The problem with this is twofold:

- The popup window obscures code behind it. This is a problem if you are copying code from the lines which happen to be obscured, or you just need to see those lines of code for any reason.
- The popup window steals keystrokes, such as arrow key navigation movements and, obviously, pressing Enter.

The second of these issues can be addressed by re-assigning the key bindings so that, for example, CTRL+UDLR is used instead of UDLR arrow keys.

I don't know how to resolve the first problem.

I do *not* want to disable Intellisense completely, as I then loose some useful features, such as being able to look up where classes/types are defined from the Right Click menu.

Since I am working on a large codebase, this feature is pretty much non-optional.

Is there a way to prevent the popup from showing *automatically*. In an ideal world, I would like to be able to assign a keyboard shortcut to trigger the Intellisense popup to load, but I don't know if that is possible?

In short

- How do I stop the Intellisense popup from showing without disabling Intellisense
- Can I assign a keyboard shortcut to trigger the popup to load if I want to see the autocomplete suggestions at a particular time?

Note: When I say *Intellisense* I mean the information that the C++ Extension Pack provides. It might be called something different, I know it as Intellisense from using Visual Studio back in the day.

**Related Questions**

- [Visual Studio Code how to disable these extra inserted lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171185)
- [Visual Studio Code - Prevent Intellisense popup without disabling Intellisense completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484469)
- [How do I disable this Visual Studio Code popup from being shown automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111412)
- [How can I disable automatic showing of parameter hints and enable manually showing using a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906079)

Comment: I should add, I have already tried unticking the context specific options for this. Settings>Editor>Show Functions is one example. But if I understand correctly (I'm not convinced that I do) this disables Intellisense for function contexts which isn't what I want.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/75310821/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I have half an answer after accidentally discovering this keyboard shortcut: `CTRL + I`

It seems that the default mapping for `Trigger Suggest` is what I was looking for, and answers part of this question.

I still don't know how to stop the popup raising itself by default. If I can get that to stop happening, then `CTRL + I` can be used to trigger the suggestions box to be shown.

[image: VS Code Suggestion Keyboard Shortcut]

#### Edit: There is now a solution for this:

see [this Stack Overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111412/how-do-i-disable-this-visual-studio-code-popup-from-being-shown-automatically)

Answer (score 3):

You could specify super long delay in settings like this
`"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 60000` (it's in milliseconds so it will automatically show only after a minute, but still can be triggered with shortcut), here are the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

I believe there was also a setting to set a number of needed characters after which it will trigger suggestions but i can't find it right now.

To trigger suggestion with shortcut find `Trigger Suggest` in shortcut list (open Command Pallet and search for `Keyboard Shortcuts`), by default it's `CTRL+Space`

Comment: I might have to ask the devs for this feature, but my suggestions don't usually get enough upvotes on github to motivate them to implement them