# How to get rid of automatic auto complete in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm getting autocomplete without prompting for it by pressing any buttons, menu items, hint popups, or keyboard shortcuts.

I am not sure if it's due to some extension I added. I am new to coding and while this autocomplete is helpful, it wouldn't make me a better programmer. I was wondering how to turn off this setting in VSCode window.

I want them to be totally off.

Comment: "_it wouldn't make me a better programmer_" sounds like an opinion (which we tend to be reserved about here). It depends what you think a better programmer is- one who doesn't need to rely on certain tools, or one who makes the best usage of their tools by relying on them. There are tradeoffs and in many cases it's a matter of taste. I just though it important to acknowledge that.

Comment: There are other more objective reasons why some people might want to disable automatic (non-prompted) autocomplete- performance limitations of the dev's machine is one. Or just finding it annoying to have constant little popups while typing.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, quick suggestions can be disabled for with the following config:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": "off",
    "strings": "off",
    "other": "off"
}
```

If you want to have different settings per language, you can do it like so (using C++ as an example):

```json
"[cpp]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off",
        "other": "off"
    }
},
```

From your screenshot, it looks like you have these values set to `"inline"`, which shows them as "ghost text".

Specifically for C++ (and perhaps for similar scenarios with other languages), the quick suggestions may still pop up after typing some characters such as the [scope resolution operator (`::`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), but most cases of it will be disabled with this (and I don't know how to fix those specific cases or why they happen (might be worth issue tickets with the tool maintainers)). You can take a look at the `editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter` setting.

This allows you to still trigger autocomplete suggestions by pressing the registered keyboard shortcut. If you actually want to entirely disable intellisense for whichever programming language and extension you are using, that generally just means disabling/deactivating that extension, or using specific settings for that extension to disable intellisense.