# How can I disable automatic showing of parameter hints and enable manually showing using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to prevent a VS Code popup from appearing automatically, becuase I find it distracting, and because it covers up other important lines of code nearby which I often want to be able to see.

I do not want to totally disable this popup. I want to be able to control when it appears using a keyboard shortcut.

The popup is shown in the screenshot below. I have highlighted it by drawing a red box around it so that it is clear what I am talking about. I do not know what this popup is called, or if it has a "technical" name.

[image: vs code popup]

#### What causes it?

I believe this popup appears when a language Intellisense extension is enabled. But I am not 100 % sure about this.

It appears to show information pulled from documentation comments, so it would make sense that it is part of an Intellisense system.

This information is **sometimes, but rarely useful**. Most of the time, as developers, we are editing existing code, often code which we wrote or are familiar with. Therefore it does not make sense that a box containing documentation is shown by defualt for every class, function, etc, that we type.

How can it be disabled by default so that it does not appear unless the developer asks for it, for example by pressing a keyboard shortcut?

#### Why is it a problem?

- As can be seen from the screenshot, the popup obscures many lines of code by its presence. This is bad because sometimes we want to see information in those lines of code. We sometimes want to read lines of code which are below the current cursor position.
- Animation. The popup follows the current cursor position, and its contents changes as the programmer is typing. This animation (change in position and what is being shown) is distracting. If the box were rendered in a fixed location, it would be less distracting. The fact that it follows the cursor position, right next to the current cursor position, is bad.

---

Edit: The following information might help guide towards a solution. I have discovered this is the "Parameter Suggestions Popup". It can be totally disabled by un-selecting this Settings Option.

[image: parameter popup setting]

However, this does not answer the question, because I do not want to totally disable it.

**Related Questions**

- [Visual Studio Code how to disable these extra inserted lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171185)
- [Visual Studio Code - Prevent Intellisense popup without disabling Intellisense completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484469)
- [How do I disable this Visual Studio Code popup from being shown automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111412)
- [How can I disable automatic showing of parameter hints and enable manually showing using a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906079)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, this feature/mechanism in VS Code is called "Parameter Hints". To make its display/opening manually triggered by keyboard shortcut instead of automatically triggered, set `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`, and then bind your keyboard shortcut of choice to the `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command.

Comment: For future reference there is a keybinding for "triggerSuggest" as well. This is the other popup which might appear depending on your settings. I haven't yet figured out how to disable or enable this by default.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I believe the setting you are looking for there is `editor.quickSuggestions`.

Comment: That seems like it might be the thing. Actually in this case it doesn't make a lot of sense to turn that off because if you want suggestions then you want them to be shown *while typing*, which is the opposite of what you want for documentation information. In other words, if you want documentation, you will pause typing to read it, so it makes no sense for it to be shown while typing. Thanks for letting me know where the setting is though. I note there is an option for "inline" which some people may prefer.