# How do I disable this Visual Studio Code popup from being shown automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The below shown popup appears after typing a `.` character. How can I prevent it from being shown automatically?

Ideally I would like to assign it to a shortcut key so that I can still choose to show it should I wish to do so.

[image]

**Related Questions**

- [Visual Studio Code how to disable these extra inserted lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171185)
- [Visual Studio Code - Prevent Intellisense popup without disabling Intellisense completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484469)
- [How do I disable this Visual Studio Code popup from being shown automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111412)
- [How can I disable automatic showing of parameter hints and enable manually showing using a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906079)

Comment: This is to do with VSCode intellisense. A similar question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to VSCode docs:

`You can customise your IntelliSense experience in settings and key bindings.`

In your `settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
    ...
}
```

For more info, see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

To manually view them, on mac press fn+ctrl+space

You could customise the combination by changing your `keybindings.json`

```
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+space",
    "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
    "when": "editorHasCompletionItemProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  ...
]
```

For more info, see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_key-bindings

Comment: It's also available in the Settings editor under `Editor: Suggest on Trigger Characters`, apparently. Thanks