# Visual Studio Code how to disable these extra inserted lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I don't know what causes these extra "annotation" lines to be inserted. I don't even know what the "correct" name for them is. All I know it I want them to go away.

I suspect that this is caused by the `rust-analyzer` extension. But I can't be completely sure.

[image]

**Related Questions**

- [Visual Studio Code how to disable these extra inserted lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171185)
- [Visual Studio Code - Prevent Intellisense popup without disabling Intellisense completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484469)
- [How do I disable this Visual Studio Code popup from being shown automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111412)
- [How can I disable automatic showing of parameter hints and enable manually showing using a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906079)

Comment: it appears as part of a thing called CodeLens. there should be an option to turn it off.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Thank you, it is apparently `SETTINGS > "LENS" > Rust-analyzer > Lens : Enable` = false

Comment: @gbjbaanb If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm cool, only knew how it works in fullfat VS.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "Code Lens". See also ([the VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup)).

For the general case of all files, see [How to disable codelens in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34356510/11107541) (TL;DR set `editor.codeLens` to `false`).

For [the Rust Analyzer extension](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/tree/master/editors/code) in particular, use either its general `rust-analyzer.lens.enable` setting, or if you want to go more fine grained, use the `rust-analyzer.lens.*.enable` settings. See also [The Rust Analyzer's Manual's section on Configuration](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual#configuration) or [its extension package.json](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/blob/master/editors/code/package.json).